# Young, one out of two of the only girls and British

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, finding-other-players

Okay, so I'm 13/14, a dnd nerd, a beginner, in a dnd club and has seen enough of the Internet to be pretty f---ed up. I live in Cambridge, England and I really wanna find a good dnd group. I've never played before but I am starting a bi weekly campaign in an all boys (except me and a best friend of mine) warhammer and dnd club. It's warhammer one week and dnd the next and so on. I have a backstory, drawing and stats for my elven character but I want to find a safe place that I could maybe join. Packed schedule but room can be made. I am open to dirty jokes, swear words and all of that but I live with my parents so yeah. Sorry if this sounds like an ad but I am genuinely looking for some nerds to chill with and play some trpg!

Comment: Hi! We don't take looking-for-group ads here as we're focused on Q&A. Please see the linked duplicates instead.

Comment: Also see other questions with the [finding-other-players] tag (which I've added to the question).